# Are photoshop like blend modes possible with html5 and draggable images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, photoshop

I'm using some javascript to make my images [draggable](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=dragable-content)

I want to be able to move my images over each other and create a similar effect to the multiply blending mode in photoshop.

I've seen how this is possible with static images, but I want these to change as they are moved around the screen, rather than just loading up with the effect already applied.

Is this possible within the canvas? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possibile with Canvas and processing.js, but you will not be able to use your actual draggable plugin (it doesn't seem HTML5).

Read this http://processingjs.org/reference/blend_/ but remember Blending on Canvas could be very slow (it depends by images' resolution and by Browser' engine).